# get request timeout PDO connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect to remotemysql on another server and i've all the authentications and these authentication are working well to connect to remote sql in VISUAL STUDIO and PHP STORM but when i open up the url royalresidency.pk/administration and try to login and it gives me this error i don't understand this error i tried to allow that from from remotesql also and also this ip is allow but still i can't get access to sql from this server what can be the issue ?

```
  $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=65.60.37.227;dbname=cricflip_RoyalResidency',$dbuser, $dbpass);
                return $connect;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your mysql connection. Try connecting with command line. (Mysql should be preinstalled in your system)

mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -h REMOTE_SERVER_IP DB_NAME

Comment: sir kindly suggest me that from where i should connect command line ? as i mentioned in my post that i've tried these connection from PHPSTORM and VISUALSTUDIO to connect MYSQL database . Everything is working fine there. But here is issue

Comment: Try these codes. 

`$connect = new PDO( "mysql:host=65.60.37.227;dbname=cricflip_RoyalResidency", $dbuser, $dbpass, array( PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => "180", 
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
 ) );`